# Where can I find clean maps of colonial America?

Tags: maps, resource

I have been trying to find maps of North America with the various territories, but the closest I can find are actual maps made from that time.

Where can I find clean, modern (projection) maps of North America from the 1600's onward?

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"? In what ways are modern maps more "clean" than older ones?

Comment: I find it difficult to see how your question is related with history. What's the purpose of this map? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @RobertColumbia When I say clean, I mean in the way modern maps are, flat backgrounds, just territories etc.

Comment: @Rathony it is asking for modern versions of historical maps

Comment: I think I would begin my research with the Lewis and Clark expedition. They were the first to make the overland trip from the East Coast to Oregon and make it back safely.

Comment: The Wikipedia article "Territorial evolution of North America since 1763" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_evolution_of_North_America_since_1763 has a series of "clean", similarly formatted maps. The first two are pre-revolutionary ie colonial. I can also recommend the article as a good read.

Comment: @IanF1 I started there to, but they only go back to the 1700's as you said, I need back to 1600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/histus.html

There you go. Map collection.

Answer (score 3):

The [Library of Congress](http://www.loc.gov) has a search engine where you can search specifically for [maps](https://www.loc.gov/maps). E.g. the search term "[1600](https://www.loc.gov/maps/?q=1600)" leads to some historical maps.